# rsync output file sizes in human-readable format

Tags: linux, rsync

when you use

```
rsync -avzh --stats --out-format="%t %f %b"
```

it does the output in bytes the man pages says the following

```
In addition, one or more apostrophes may be specified prior to a   
numerical escape to indicate that the numerical value should be made   
more human-readable. The 3 supported levels are the same as for the  
--human-readable command-line option, though the default is for human-  
readability to be off. Each added apostrophe increases the level  
(e.g. "%''l %'b %f").
```

my question is how many apostrophes do I have to place between the %b to change it from bytes to mega  bytes?

As soon as i add a apostrophes this is what happens in the log

```
rsync -av  --out-format="%t %f %'b"



2016/10/29 01:00:22 home/data/Clients/P/Power Solutions CC/2017/Sales Report %'b
```

I have typed the command out as not to copy html but cant seem to get the log to display correctly

Answer (score 17):

Reading the `--human-readable` section of the man page reveals

> **-h, --human-readable**
>
> Output numbers in a more human-readable format. This makes big numbers output using larger units, with a K, M, or G suffix. If this option was specified once, these units are K (1000), M (1000*1000), and G (1000*1000*1000); if the option is repeated, the units are powers of 1024 instead of 1000.

However that's not especially clear so let's bring [Scientific Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) to bear and devise an experiment. We'll use some files we have lying around and use rsync to copy them. We'll make a note of the relevant outputs it generates for each of the different command line options.

Here are the files we'll perform the experiment with.

```
ls -lh test.*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 iain iain     40435 Oct 31 09:08 test.png
-rw-rw-r--. 1 iain iain 853483520 Oct 31 09:08 test.tar
```

then we'll use rsync to copy them. Note that we delete the destination files each time but not show outr working.

**Test 1**

```
rsync -av  --out-format="%t %f %b" ./test.* /tmp/
sending incremental file list
2016/10/31 09:10:42 test.png 40482
2016/10/31 09:10:45 test.tar 853587747
```

so `%b` gives a simple bytes value

**Test 2**

```
rsync -av  --out-format="%t %f %'b" ./test.tar /tmp/
sending incremental file list
2016/10/31 09:11:25 test.png 40,482
2016/10/31 09:11:28 test.tar 853,587,747
```

`%'b` gives a bytes value separated by `,`

**Test 3**

```
rsync -av  --out-format="%t %f %''b" ./test.* /tmp/
sending incremental file list
2016/10/31 09:12:29 test.png 40.48K
2016/10/31 09:12:32 test.tar 853.59M
```

`%''b` gives the KB/MB (and GB) sizes scaled appropriately

and finally

**Test 4**

```
rsync -av  --out-format="%t %f %'''b" ./test* /tmp/
sending incremental file list
2016/10/31 09:17:49 test.png 39.53K
2016/10/31 09:17:52 test.tar 814.04M
```

`%'''b` gived the values in KiB/MiB etc also scaled appropriately.

**Conclusion**

If you want everything expressing in MB then you can't do what you want as the output is scaled to K/M/G etc as appropriate for the file.

If you want K/M/G etc B then `''` and if you want KiB/MiB/GiB etc then `'''` is what you want.

So, the answer to your question is, it depends on what you mean by

> change it from bytes to mega bytes

Comment: Thank you your answer explains very clearly what the different levels are. If i use the code in the log file as soon as i move from %b to %'b i dont get the numbers anymore but  %'b I have typed it out so not to copy the html I will edit my question to make my question more clear as it is in fact 2 questions

Comment: the command `ls -lh` is wrong, this is the output of `ls -l`